# Is elastic search data access sync or async?

Tags: elasticsearch

As i am new to elastic search.how will elasticsearch work in concurrency.How search work and write/update/delete work in one node.Every request is processed one by one or it wil work simutaneously.

```
 will it support transaction ??
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: as for as my understanding write operations are sync and reas and search operations are sync..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRUD requests happen in parallel within a single shard (you can have multiple shards on a single node).  Transactions are not supported.

A bulk request (multiple CRUD requests in a single request) and processed serially on a single shard, but you can have multiple bulk requests processed in parallel on a single shard.  They don't support transactions either.  The success or failure of one request within a bulk request doesn't affect the others.

To ensure that one update doesn't overwrite changes from another, Elasticsearch provides optimistic concurrency control: you specify the `version` number of the doc you want to update. If the current `version` is different, then the update will fail and you can take the appropriate action.

See [versioning](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-versioning) and the `retry_on_conflict` parameter on the [update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).